# When can the covariance matrix $X^TX$ be semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, covariance

I have a matrix $X$ (of shape $[2, 512]$) which consists of $2$ observations of $512$ dimensional feature vector.

I thought that given that $x_0$ and $x_1$ are linearly independent (they contain a lot of $0$s), it would imply that after centering $X = X - \mu(X)$, we can say that $X^TX$ is at least semi definite.

However, in my experiment, I am getting large negative eigenvalues, which is contradictory. So, my question is under what conditions is $X^TX$ semi definite?

Comment: For any real matrix $X$, the corresponding Gram matrix $X^TX$ is always positive semi-definite. How did you compute the eigenvalues?

Comment: @SangchulLee I'm computing them using `numpy` in Python... I'll try to come up with a reproducible example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always, if your matrix is real. Because if $X^TXv=\lambda v$ with $v$ a unit vector, then 
$$
\lambda=v^T(\lambda v)=v^TX^TXv=(Xv)^TXv\geq0. 
$$
If $X$ is not real, it is possible for $X^TX$ be fail to be positive semidefinite; in the complex case, the right notion is the *adjoint* $X^*$, which is the conjugate tranpose.

Comment: I'm confused, shouldn't the first word be "never" as the question is about when can the covariance matrix have negative eigenvalues?

Comment: I'm not answering the title, I'm answering the text. The question is when is $X^TX$ is semidefinite. I see the contradiction, though :D

Comment: I see. I guess, changing the title to conform with the text would be better.